# How to emit component's method from router-view?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have 50 models and for All model CRUDs, I would like to make toolbar for each page (like index, create, update, delete and etc.).

Look at this picture please:

[image]

## My folder structure:

[image]

## App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul class="nav">
      <router-link to="/posts">Posts</router-link>|
      <router-link to="/products">Products</router-link>|
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <router-view class="content"/>

    <hr>

    <router-view name="toolbar" />

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Posts from "./views/posts/Index";
import Products from "./views/products/Index";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Posts,
    Products
  },
  data() {
    return {
      status: "This is the default status message"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

## views/posts/Index.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="card-header">
            <span>test</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {   
    methods: {
        my_func(type) {
            this.$notification[type]({
                message: "Notification Title",
                description: "This test."
            });
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

## views/posts/components/Toolbar.vue

```
<template>
    <toolbar>
        <toolbar-section>
            <div class="toolbar-link">
                <button></button>
            </div>
        </toolbar-section>
    </toolbar>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            checked: null
        };
    },

    methods: {
        update: function() {
            this.$emit("my_func");
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/trigger-event-views-165yz?fontsize=14

## UPDATE

Now, I want when the user clicks on the edit button, I check the table and find the selected row and redirect to the update page and if a row does not select, something alerted.

Comment: Did you already take a look at a eventbus with vue https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: @dreijntjens I have 50 models and making 7 global events for each model does not make sense. Right?

Comment: I think I've to few details to answer this correctly. I don't think the thing you're trying to achieve is possible. But I'm actually curious what you are trying to achieve. is it sub routing?

Comment: Switch to using `Vuex`. You can load your data from a central store and don't need to use events altogether. For example you can store an array of values in Vuex and every component that references the array gets reactive data. You would need to make a suitable mapping but the code will be more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal I used `Vuex` and everything seems good. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have a another vue instance just for Events.

vueEventManager.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';

class vueEventManager {
  constructor() {
      this.vue = new Vue;
  }
  trigger(event, data = null) {
      this.vue.$emit(event, data);
  }
  listen(event, callback) {
      this.vue.$on(event, callback);
  }
  off(event, callback) {
      this.vue.$off(event, callback);
  }
  once(event, callback) {
      this.vue.$once(event, callback);
  }
}

export default vueEventManager;
```

Then you can register it in your main.js file:

```
import vueEventManager from './folder/vueeventmanager';
window.Event = new vueEventManager();
```

Now you can use it in your components to emit events.

```
Event.trigger('eventName', {'valueName': value})
```

And listen to them

```
Event.listen('eventName', (value) => {
            //do something
        });
```

Comment: I have 50 models and making 7 global events for each model does not make sense. What is your opinion?